# Remove `status-publish` with Genesis x Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, genesis

Created a template.php and would like to remove

`<article class="post-11 page type-page status-publish entry" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork">`

this from my body.. I imagine there's a Genesis function however I am unable to find on here or via google..

Any help is gr8ly appreciated..

Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    add_filter( 'genesis_attr_entry', 'change_my_attributes_entry' );
/**
 * Remove a class for entry element.
 *
 * 
 *
 * @param array $attributes Existing attributes for entry element.
 * @return array Amended attributes for entry element.
 */
function change_my_attributes_entry( $attributes ) {
    $classes= get_post_class();
    if( ( $key = array_search( 'status-publish', $classes ) ) !== false )
        unset( $classes[$key] );
    $attributes['class'] = join( ' ', $classes );


    return $attributes;

}
```